# How can we rename a field or give alias to field in MongoDB Atlas charts?

Tags: mongodb, charts, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-charts

How can we  rename a field or give alias to field in MongoDB Atlas charts?

Answer (score 0):

Examples:
this is the *students* collection

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "alias": [ "The American Cincinnatus", "The American Fabius" ],
  "mobile": "555-555-5555",
  "nmae": { "first" : "george", "last" : "washington" }
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "alias": [ "My dearest friend" ],
  "mobile": "222-222-2222",
  "nmae": { "first" : "abigail", "last" : "adams" }
}
```

Here I update the *nmae* field to *name*

```
db.students.updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "nmae": "name" } } )

{
  "_id": 1,
  "alias": [ "The American Cincinnatus", "The American Fabius" ],
  "mobile": "555-555-5555",
  "name": { "first" : "george", "last" : "washington" }
},
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "alias" : [ "My dearest friend" ],
   "mobile" : "222-222-2222",
   "name" : { "first" : "abigail", "last" : "adams" }
}
```

ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: If there is any confusion and query please feel free to ask me.
Thank you.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, can I achieve this in Atlas charts ?.As per my knowledge in Atlas we drag and drop the fields, how do I rename the field there?